# Possible to .push() to a dynamically named key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dynamic, foreach

I have an object that I would like to push an indeterminate amount of other objects to, using a loop. To keep it organized, I'd like to dynamically name the keys based on them amount of times the loop runs. I have the following:

```js
let formsJson = {};
let counter = 1;

//savedForms are where the objects that I want to push reside
savedForms.forEach( form => {
  formsJson['form'+counter] = JSON.parse(form.firstDataBit_json);

  //This is where I'm having trouble

  counter = counter + 1;
});
```

I can push the first bit of data fine, and name the key dynamically as well. But I need to push 2 more objects to this same dynamic key, and that's where I'm having trouble. If I try the obvious and do:

```js
formsJson['form'+counter].push(JSON.parse(form.secondDataBit_JSON));
```

I don't get any output. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: From what I see here your keys are simply an incremental count of the number of forms inside the object. I think you would be better off using an array than an associative array here. Can you tell us why you chose to use an associative array to begin with?

Comment: `Object.assign(formsJson['form'+counter], newObj)` assuming the keys in the new object don't overlap.. not quite sure what the actual end goal is here. Other answers suggest using an array instead, this is just another approach.

Comment: @CalvinEllis I'm pulling all rows of data that match the user's ID, from SQL (through express). The user can have an indeterminate number of forms saved in the SQL table, and each row (form) is composed of 3 columns of JSON data. Thus the need to parse them and send each to a dynamic key. hopefully that makes sense :)

Comment: @rlemon That's interesting, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forEach() gives you access to the index already. No need to create the `counter` variable. [Example usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Printing_the_contents_of_an_array). I would definitely recommend using a simple index, and not using the `'form'+counter` key.

In your example, it's not clear to me that the value being assigned in the forEach loop is an array. So it's unclear if you can `push` to any given element in that. But generally that syntax should

Personally, I would prefer to have a function that outputs the entire value of the element. That would provide better encapsulation, testability, and help enforce default values. Something like:

```
function createItem(param1) { 
  let item = [];
  item.push(param1.someElement);
  if (foo) {
    item.push(...);
  } else {
    item.push(...);
  }
  return item;
}

formsJson['form'+counter] = createItem( JSON.parse(form) )
```

Comment: This is a good solution, and with some minor adjustments, it got me to what I needed to do. I ended up tweaking how I was doing a few things on the original question, since they were incorrect for my purposes. However, this answers the original problem. Thank you for setting me on the right path :)

Answer (score 0):

So you're making `formsJson['form'+counter]` a by assigning the JSON parse, not an array as you want. Try this:

```
formsJson['form'+counter] = [];
formsJson['form'+counter].push(JSON.parse(form.firstDataBit_json));
formsJson['form'+counter].push(JSON.parse(form.secondDataBit_JSON));
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't get any output (last line of my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to figure out something like this

```
savedforms.forEach((form, index)  => 
 formsJson[`form${index + 1}`] = [ JSON.parse(form.secondDataBit_JSON)])
```

Now you can push on the item

```
formsJson[`form${index + 1}`].push(JSON.parse(form.secondDataBit_JSON));`
```

Also here you'll save operation on incrementing it will be automaticly